# Why is a ServiceBehavior an attribute of the Service Class and not the Contract?

Tags: wcf, servicebehavior

I've found plenty of places where people point out that a ServiceBehavior should be an attribute of the service class and not the contract, and this definitely seems to be the case. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it deals with **implementation detail** of the service and is **not part of the contract**.

Behaviours such as session, re-entry,... all deal with the implementation so that you could have the same contract (interface) but different implementations exposed at different endpoints.